# File Uploading Spring Webflow 2.3 and Security

Tags: spring-security, spring-webflow

Has anyone had an issue with doing file uploads using Spring Webflow 2.3 and Spring Security? Anytime I have a JSP page with the enctype="multipart/form-data" it all goes up in flames. I have added this:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000"/>
</bean>
```

into the Spring config as well as having the commons-fileupload JAR available to the application

Comment: Please post any exceptions if you are getting in your logs

Answer (score 0):

Increase the `maxUploadSize` as `value="1048576"`, strangely it doesn't throw any exception.